# WebAuthenticationBroker for WPF and WP8

Tags: wpf, authentication

The WebAuthenticationBroker scheme in Windows Store apps is not bad. What would be the equivalent for WP8 and WPF? It would be nice to write once and use a similar system on each platform. Is DotNetOpenAuth still recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I have build a WebAuthenticationBroker for WP7 (which would work ofcourse for WP8 too)
Inside the wrapper I've build for AzureMobileServices for WP7.

I haven't migrated it to a standalone project, it is part of a .Net wrapper i've build.

**Let me know if it helps!**

Watch Option **(2)** for Login here:
https://github.com/zaxy78/azure-mobile-wp7-sdk#login-to-azure-mobile-services